# i can't get 3d glb model from wwwroot folder

Tags: three.js, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an asp.net core mvc application, I want to show a 3d model on a page using three js, three js works without the 3d model, but when i want to add the model, I get the error

> https://localhost:7256/mod/monkey_textured.glb net::ERR_ABORTED 404

If I don't make an asp.net core mvc application and host it directly, the application works fine, you can see it from this link -> https://www.testapp-1.com/

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import Stats from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module'

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(5))
scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight( 'white', 'white', 1 ));
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
)
camera.position.z = 2

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.enableDamping = true


const arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
    new THREE.Vector3(),
    new THREE.Vector3(),
    0.25,
    0xffff00
)
scene.add(arrowHelper)

const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()

const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
const coneGeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry(0.05, 0.2, 8)

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
const sceneMeshes: THREE.Object3D[] = []

const loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load(
    '/mod/monkey_textured.glb',
    function (gltf) {
        gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
            if ((child as THREE.Mesh).isMesh) {
                const m = child as THREE.Mesh
                m.receiveShadow = true
                m.castShadow = true
                ;(m.material as THREE.MeshStandardMaterial).flatShading = true
                sceneMeshes.push(m)
            }
            if ((child as THREE.Light).isLight) {
                const l = child as THREE.SpotLight
                l.castShadow = true
                l.shadow.bias = -0.003
                l.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048
                l.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048
            }
        })
        scene.add(gltf.scene)
    },
    (xhr) => {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    }
)

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry()
const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    wireframe: true,
})

const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1)
scene.add(cube)

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    render()
}


const mouse = new THREE.Vector2()


const stats = new Stats()
document.body.appendChild(stats.dom)

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    render()
    stats.update()
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()
```